# React Flow: is it possible to detect when all edges are initialized like it's already possible with nodes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, callback, draw, react-flow

I'm developing a component in my React application that will use the React Flow component.

Context: I would need to know when the nodes and edges have finished initializing because as soon as this initialization is complete, I need to take a screenshot of my flow.

For the moment, I only found the useNodesInitialized hook which actually detects when the nodes have finished initializing. However, I don't see any other functions/hooks for the edges. Do you have any idea how I could tell if the edges are initialized?
Or maybe I missed the information in the documentation?

Setting a timeout cannot be possible unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

This is what my screenshot looks like when I check if the useNodesInitialized hook is set to true:

[image]

And this is what I would like it to look like:

[image]